# Connection issues since update to 10.0

Tags: sonos

Since updating the system to version 10.0, my service has been experiencing connection issues while playing a track. I have not done any changes recently server side (however I don't want to rule out that I'm doing something wrong).

**Here's what happens:**

1. Hit Play
2. Track starts playing
3. After about 1 min to 1.30 min, I get the message in the controller: "Unable to play [track name] - the connection to [service] was lost.
4. After another few seconds the service skips to the next songs.

A few things to note:

- I have received complaints about this issue from a few customers, only after the latest update, so I don't believe these are intermittent WiFi issues.
- I have tested with serving the streaming files locally from my laptop and it works fine.

Based on all of this, I believe there is an issue in the connection between the Sonos player and the streaming server (or CDN). I'm out of ideas though, on what I should be looking for. Requests, headers etc. look fine to me.

Is there any other way to troubleshoot or see what is actually happening when the Sonos player "looses connection to the service"?

Thanks much

Comment: For reliability issues like this, it's best to communicate through our basecamp project. Please start a new conversation there.